# Why can't I use LINQ with WorkItemCollection

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the COM interface to TFS. (TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient v14.95.3). I am trying to use LINQ to iterate over the various collections. For example, this function **works great**:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetTitles(WorkItemCollection workItemList)
    {
        return from WorkItem item in workItemList select item.Fields["Title"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

However, when I try to change to use the method syntax it fails:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetTitles2(WorkItemCollection workItemList)
    {
        return workItemList.Select(item => item.Fields["Title"].Value.ToString());
    }
```

... gives me error **"'WorkItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select'..."**

I have `using System.Linq;` in my file. And I am referencing `System.Core.dll`. The `WorkItemCollection` *does* implement `IEnumerable`.  So why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WorkItemCollection` does only implement `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<WorkItem>`. The LINQ extensions are declared only for `IEnumerable<T>`, not for the non-generic `IEnumerable`.

What you can do is use `OfType<T>()`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTitles2(WorkItemCollection workItemList)
{
    return workItemList.OfType<WorkItem>()
                       .Select(item => item.Fields["Title"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Instead of `OfType<T>` you can also use `Cast<T>`. But if there is something other than a `WorkItem` in the sequence (which is probably never the case in this scenario), `Cast<T>` would throw an `InvalidCastException` while `OfType<T>` would ignore that element.

Answer (score 6):

`WorkItemCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.  It's the latter, generic, interface that is the foundation of LINQ.

You can convert from one to the other using the `Cast<T>` extension method, however:

```
workItemList.Cast<WorkItem>.Select(item => ...
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly. I wish i could accept both answers :)